# Separate UIHints for display and edit in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Is it possible to have separate uihint templates, one for display and the other for edit? If yes, how to achieve this?

For ex:

```
public class PartyRole
{
[Required]
    [UIHint("DropDownList")]
    public int PartyRoleTypeId { get; set; }
}
```

I am using EditForModel() and DisplayForModel().

In edit, I am showing the property as drop down. But in display I should show it as simple text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to have separate uihint templates, one for display and the other for edit?

No, this is not possible. It should be the same name. The EditorTemplate is located in `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` and the display template in `~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates`. If for some reason you absolutely needed to have different names for the templates you could pass them as parameter to the helpers instead of using UIHint:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Foo, "SomeEditorTemplate")

@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Foo, "SomeDisplayTemplate")
```

Comment: Thanks darin for your answer. I am showing my grid as per the article http://haacked.com/archive/2010/05/05/asp-net-mvc-tabular-display-template.aspx. However I am quiet not sure how to show foreign keys as text.Right now only foreign key ids are being displayed. I raised a separate question on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050711/handle-foreign-keys-in-mvc4-datagird-view, but got no answers :(